# Add an icon to the achievement list when new privilege has earned in apps

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, privileges

Achievements list doesn't contain an icon for new privilege for both iOS and Android apps:

> [image: iOS]
>
> [image: Android]

Web contains an icon either:

> [image: web]

Is it possible to add same icon as in web?

Comment: @animuson should the FR be closed as a dupe for BUG?